# iPhone EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling [super dealloc] on a custom UIViewController

Tags: iphone, dealloc

I'm at a loss! It's one of those pesky bugs that happens only under specific conditions, yet I cannot link the conditions and the results directly.

My app has a paged UIScrollView where each page's view comes from a MyViewController, a subclass of UITableViewController. To minimize memory usage I unload those controllers that are not currently visible. Here is my "cleaning" method:

```
- (void) cleanViewControllers:(BOOL)all {

    if (all) { 
    // called if some major changes occurred and ALL controllers need to be cleared

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [viewControllers count]; i++)
            [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    else if ([viewControllers count] > 2) {
    // called if only the nearest, no longer visible controller need to be cleared
        NSInteger i = pageControl.currentPage - 2;
        if (i > -1) [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
        i = pageControl.currentPage + 2;
        if (i < [viewControllers count]) [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}
```

It's this line that crashes the app:

```
viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
```

viewControllers is an NSMutableArray containing objects of type MyViewController. MyViewController has no custom properties and its dealloc method contains nothing but a [super dealloc] call.

Here is what the debugger shows:
[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img831/3610/screenshot20100806at126.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img831/3610/screenshot20100806at126.png)

The thing is that this does not happen every time the controller is cleared, but only sometimes. Specifically, after certain changes trigger a complete cleaning and re-drawing of the ScrollView, it displays the current page (call it X) fine, but as soon as I scroll far enough to cause cleaning of X, this crash happens. It's driving me nuts!

Another thing, this does not happen in the 4.0 Simulator, nor on an iPad, but happens very consistently on a 1st gen iPod touch running 3.1.3.

Comment: ultimately, i ended up refactoring the code to perform unloading at a different point in the execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something is being released but a pointer is still dangling.  Set NSZombieEnabled to YES and run it again.  Here's how:

- Product -> Edit Scheme
- Select the "Arguments" tab
- Add to "Variables to be set in the environment"

  - Name: NSZombieEnabled
  - Value: YES

In Xcode 4.1 and above:

- Product -> Edit Scheme
- Select the "Diagnostics" tab

  - You have an option to enable zombie objects.

Run the app again.  At some point it'll tell you you're accessing an already released object.  From that you'll need to figure out who's not retaining or who's over-releasing the object.

Happy Zombie Hunting.

Comment: Zombie Hunting? Sounds like fun! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Often this can be caused by allocing something then setting it to something within the ViewController then releasing it, for example:

```
UIBarButtonItem* timeLabel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"time" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: timeLabel, nil];

self.toolbarItems = items;
```

Now the natural thing to do after this is :

```
[timeLabel release];
```

But this will cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS on [super dealloc], presumably because the view controller releases the array AND all the items within it.

Answer (score 0):

View controllers will automatically unload their views on a memory warning by default, so there's no reason to unload the controllers themselves unless they include significant overhead.

Is the view controller's view still in the view hierarchy? You can check with something like `[viewController isViewLoaded] && viewController.view.superview`. If so, it's probably not safe to remove the view controller.

(Note the isViewLoaded check, since UIViewController.view will load the view if it's not already loaded.)

Comment: unfortunately, especially on older hardware such as 1st gen iPod touch, the extra views do slow things down considerably.

Comment: Then use `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` first?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of replacing the elements in the array you can simply call `removeObjectAtIndex:` or `removeAllObjects:` to make sure there is nothing holding reference where it shouldn't.

Comment: There is no need to insert null values into the array when the objects could be removed instead. Won't affect retainCount but make code more readable and easier to debug (when outputting the content of the array to the console)

Comment: same thing happens if i remove the objects altogether instead of replacing with null. the reason i use null is because that way i keep track of what's loaded and displayed.

Comment: You're missing the point. a[i] contains either the view controller for page i (if it's loaded) or [NSNull null] (if it's not loaded).